# Closing the server after receiving TCP request

Tags: server, jmeter, devops, performance-testing, tcpclient

I'm building a JMeter script in which I'm sending a TCP messages (both fixed length and variable length) to a server. The problem is the server doesn't sends anything at the end of the response message that may indicate that the response message is ended, resulting in the test run keeps on running and if I stop it manually it gives a 500 (Read Exception). I've by-passed this situation by adding a response time-out and a response assertion but when I load test my script all the requests fail. I've tried putting \n, \r, setting end of line to 10 etc but all in vain.

Now I've already gotten some opinions like it is due to server side settings but my question is what exactly are those settings about. Because I've to explain this blocker to non-tech persons. So is there any way that this issue can be overcome or can anyone please tell me what exactly are the server side settings that need to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

If your requests fail then your Response Assertion doesn't really act like a "workaround", either you configured it not properly or you're receiving something which is not expected by the assertion.

We cannot help you efficiently without seeing:

1. Your Response Assertion configuration
2. TCP Sampler (or whatever Sampler you're using) response from the View Results Tree listener
3. At least few lines from hte .[jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) containing results of your "load test"

If you want to mark all the Samplers as successful no matter of the real outcome you can use [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) with the following one-liner:

```
prev.setSuccessful(true)
```

Make sure to put it "high enough" so all the Samplers would be in the Assertion's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

With regards to the "server-side-settings" which we're supposed to "tell" - we don't know that "server" you're trying to test so if it's something free and open source we need to know that piece of software name.

If it's something your colleagues developed in house - I'm afraid we're not able to help at all, you'd better ask them.